# DomainDataSource and ViewModel, can it be used together?

Tags: mvvm

I want to make use of a DomainDataSource control from the RIA controls on my View, but for query parameters I have to pass the DomainDataSource to my ViewModel, currently I contruct the ViewModel in the code behind of the View and pass the DomainDataSource to the ViewModel.

This works very well as I have full control over the DomainDatasource, but I am now told by my colleagues that the way I do it breaks the pattern.

Is this true, if I pass the dds to my ViewModel do I break the pattern and further is there a way that this can be done or am I forced to fetch data only from the ViewModel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This was answered by Colin Blair in this post http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/198215.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post for Colin Blair's answer on this topic

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/198215.aspx